# How to compile local gradle module dependencies with build types?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to set up gradle modules that rely on one-another, and pass the proper build configuration between them. The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Configuration with name 'debug' not found.
```

The build type is properly declared... what do I need to add?

**Project build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.example.gradletest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug { }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

    debugCompile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'release')
}
```

**lib1 module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug { }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

    debugCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'release')
}
```

**lib2 module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug { }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines needed to be added to the "android" section of the gradle module build.gradle files:

```
defaultPublishConfig "debug"
publishNonDefault true
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies are common to release and debug.
It may work if you remove the

> debug{} // Remove this part from all modules.

from you gradle files of all the modules.